# Printing pipe output in chunks using fread() but fread() is not reading last chunk

Tags: c, windows, pipe, popen, fread

I am trying to execute a command on `Windows` with `_popen` and read the pipe's output in chunks using only fread() (I am open to another method as long as it reads in 8192 byte chunks. The reason I am reading in chunks is because I plan to use this method to send the output via TCP in 8192 chunks).

Here is my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const int BUFLEN = 8192;
    char buf[BUFLEN + 1] = { 0 };
    FILE* fpipe;

    // Call Popen to execute command and read the pipe's output.
    // the file is exactly 229401 bytes.
    fpipe = _popen("type 229401.txt", "r");

    // Store command output.
    while (fread(buf, 1, BUFLEN, fpipe)) {
        printf("%s", buf);
        //send(socket, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Close the pipe.
    _pclose(fpipe);

    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't this code read the entire file? And how do I properly read/print the entire file in chunks?

Comment: Remember that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings. Are you sure that the data in `buf` is *null-terminated*? Perhaps you should make sure it is?

Comment: Yes I initialized the buffer to all null bytes `{0}` (BUFLEN + 1) I am only storing `BUFLEN` bytes, so there's one last null byte left.

Comment: Dare I ask what that `FILE*` cast on your `_popen` call is for? That wasn't to squelch a warning, *right* ?

Comment: No it is redundant  I modified the code.

Comment: And what happens when there's a chunk that *isn't* `BUFLEN` in size? Which is typical for the very last "chunk".

Comment: That chunk is not printed to stdout.

Comment: Why not use the return value of `fread` (if > 0) as the number of bytes to be written to standard output, preferably using `fwrite` rather than `printf`?

Comment: Ian could you provide an example?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how `fread` works. If the last chunk isn't `BUFLEN` in size, then `fread` will return a value *less* than `BUFLEN` but still larger than `0` (which is a "true" value). After that it will start to return `0`.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same logic (reading in `BUFLEN` chunks) with/without fread()? If so I will accept the answer, if it works.

Comment: @imop932 Regarding remember the size and dumping to stdout, it means [something like this](https://pastebin.com/eNaV2pe9).

Comment: `size_t ret_read;` `while ((ret_read = fread(buf, 1, BUFLEN, fpipe)) > 0) {` `fwrite(buf, 1, ret_read, stdout);` `}`.

Comment: I need to send the chunks via tcp I was printing them to stdout in the example to show that fread() isn't doing what I assumed (reading in chunks even if not `BUFLEN` chunks).

Comment: When the loop ends, have you checked `feof` and `ferror` to see why it ended? If `feof` returns "true" you have read all that is to read.

Comment: Assuming the 229401 byte text input contains no ASCII NUL characters, what you were probably seeing in the output was 28 chunks of 8192 bytes input, and then the 29th chunk of output consisting of the remaining 25 bytes of input followed by the 8167 bytes from the end of the 28th chunk.

Comment: I see so maybe a do while loop would be appropriate ?

Comment: how do I ensure I don't print the last 8167 chunk/overlapping chunk in general?

Comment: "how do I ensure I don't print the last 8167 chunk/overlapping chunk in general?" By only writing the required bytes, e.g. with the `fwrite` mentioned above. If you really must use `printf("%s", buf);` then you need to place a null terminator in `buf[length_read]` first. The `printf` will output the contents of the buffer up to the first null character ('\0' or ASCII NUL) it encounters.